# Issue in maintain textsize in layout in all resolution device android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, text-size

Hello friends i have one layout which is list items in my 
**Samsung Galaxy Grad Quatrro** it looks like below

[image]

And in **HTC desire V** it looks like as below

[image]

In for both device i use same layout file which is as follow

**row.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_tops"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_imgss"
        android:layout_width="133px"
        android:layout_height="123px" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="133px"
            android:layout_height="123px"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_image_border"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_pro_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/available_rbn" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/roe_pro_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rel_imgss"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text=""
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/roe_pro_rent_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/roe_pro_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/roe_pro_name"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rel_imgss"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Rented : "
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="#686868"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_view_detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/roe_pro_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/roe_pro_rent_txt"
        android:text="DETAIL"
        android:textColor="#686868"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/roe_pro_rent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/roe_pro_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/roe_pro_name"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rel_imgss"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#282828"
        android:visibility="gone" />

     <View
        android:id="@+id/v_up"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rel_imgss"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rel_botoom"
        android:background="#e2e2e2" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_botoom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rel_imgss"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rel_imgss"
        android:background="#f4f4f4"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/roe_pro_bed"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/badroom_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="12"
            android:textColor="#282828"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#e8e8e8" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/roe_pro_bath"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bathroom_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="34"
            android:textColor="#282828"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#e8e8e8" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/roe_pro_area"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="35"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sqsize_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="1222 sqft"
            android:textColor="#282828"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#e8e8e8" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/roe_pro_unit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/unit_dropdown"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Unit 01"
            android:textColor="#282828"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

FOr above code it run fine in **Samsung Galaxy Gran Quatroo** but not work ing fine in **HTC desire V**  and  **textsize** not maintain in this two device so how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using **px** instead of **dp** as layout_width and layout_height units. Change px to dp. 
**UPDATE**

Check your device settings for fontsize. As one device might have large and other small causing the problem. The settings can be found in Settings->Display->Font Size

Comment: :: i use pixel for imageview height and with not for textsize .

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya check your device font settings in settings->display->fontsize that might be the cause for the problem. Change to medium for both the devices.